# iterate mysql query results in jade [node-mysql]

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

how can I iterate over the results of mysql query using jade.
I am using [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) .

```
[
    { 
        twitter_id: 52653645,
        screen_name: 'somoething',
        retweeted: '0'
    },
    { 
        twitter_id: 5265343636,
        screen_name: 'somoet',
        retweeted: '45'
    },
]
```

Thanks

Comment: That's not an object; as posted it's a syntax error.  Can you be more clear about the context of that code?

Comment: I have updated the question..I was confused a bit.

Comment: It's still not clear what's going on.  Are those two object literals inside an array, or what?

Comment: Sorry , I added the complete response from the query result..

Comment: [Here is the documentation.](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a9)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like I do here, when I generate the [XML feed for my blog](https://github.com/kcbanner/nodelog/blob/master/views/feed.jade).

```
ul
- each result in results
    li= result.twitter_id
    li= result.screen_name
    li= result.retweeted
```

Where `results` is your array of MySQL results passed into the template.